# "PhotoImage" typerror on pyplot.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

This minimal example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3])
plt.show()
```

using Matplotlib with Tkinter backend in Python 3.4 (Windows) throws the following exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 275, in resize
    self._tkcanvas.delete(self._tkphoto)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2316, in delete
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'delete') + args)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "PhotoImage") to tuple
```

Versions:

```
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'2.0.2'
>>> tkinter.TkVersion
8.6
>>> sys.version
'3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

Running the example is opening a Tkinter window **without** the canvas, but **with** the pyplot buttons (resize, move, ...). When I use one of the buttons (e.g. zooming into a rectangle), it is then creating the canvas. Just the initial call is throwing the exception.

I already reinstalled already matplotlib, but the problem still occurs. How can I solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the error and I am having a hard time finding anything on the net related to the typeError.

Comment: Can you install another version of python and test, like 3.6?

Comment: I'll try tomorrow, but probably I'll have to open an IT ticket and wait for the installation. I'll also do some further investigations tomorrow.

Comment: I installed a different version (WinPython, Python 3.6 also didn't work out the box) and matplotlib with the tk-backend is working fine now. I think it was something messed up with my Python setup. Anyway, I'll probably send a bug report to the matplotlib guys later.